# Create subsite using an infopath form

Tags: 2013, workflow, infopath, designer-workflow

Is it possible to create an infopath form which would allow me to create automatically a subsite when I click submit form? Can I configure workflow in that certain way or this is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

From infopath itself, natively speaking, no, you dont have any way to do it.
U could do it through InfoPath, but programmatically and it's not that hard, you could do something like this:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
  {
    using (SPSite siteCollectionOuter = new SPSite(strwebApp))
    {
      SPWebApplication webApp = siteCollectionOuter.WebApplication;
          siteCollectionOuter.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
          webApp.Sites.Add(
              strRoot //root, 
              strTitle //title,
              strDescription,  //description
              strLanguageId, //language (1033, 3082, etc)
              strWebTemplate, //site template (sts#0)
              strOwnerLogin, //Site owner
              strOwnerName, //name
              strOwnerEmail //email
          );
      siteCollectionOuter.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
  });
```